# retrieving data using Ember

Tags: json, ember.js

as I go deeper into EmberJS, I got into this context where I need to use HTTP request. As a start, I tried to retrieve JSON data so I made a test page that returns JSON and I also verified that it is in JSON by deserializing it. No errors were encountered but there is no output at all. Below are the details of my code

**application.js**

```
    App = Ember.Application.create({});

    App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        host: 'http://172.19.20.30/EmberTest/testApi.aspx'
    });
```

**event.js**

```
    App.Event = DS.Model.extend({
        title: DS.attr('string'),
        body: DS.attr('string')
    });
```

**router.js**

```
    App.Router.map(function () {
        this.resource('events', {path: '/'});
    });

    App.EventsRouter = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function () {
            return App.Event.find();
        }
    });
```

**JSON output from host**

```
    { "events": [{ "id": 1, "title": "test title", "body": "test body" },{ "id": 2, "title": "another title", "body": "another body" }] }
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="events">
    this is an example
    {{#each e in model}}
        <label>{{e.title}}</label><br />
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

what could possibly be missing in my code? comments, opinions, suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm really new to Ember, so I've only a assumption. In my App I'm using the "data-template-name" attribute for view-templates. Try to replace this to id="events".

Comment: fixed my problem! it was the router's name .. why didn't I see it -_-

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the return JSON is wrong.. it should be singular:

`{ "event": [{ "id": 1, "title": "test title", "body": "test body" },{ "id": 2, "title": "another title", "body": "another body" }] }`

When you do a find with Ember Data it should have the model name:

`this.store.find('event')` So Ember-data know where the return map to.

This will generate a URL `http://host:port/event`

If you are changing `host` it should just be the base URL you are changing and not absolute. So in your case:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://172.19.20.30/EmberTest'
});
```

Then the URL will become `http://172.19.20.30/EmberTest/events`